# Success function runs before post statement

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have a post function written in coffeescript below. The intention of the code is to post data to update events then render the view through the fetchEvents function. However, it tends to refresh the view first before it performs the update. I am looking at response time of the post for the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
  $.get '/artists/' + user_id + '/fetch_events', { event_type: action }, ((event_data) ->
    if $.isEmptyObject(event_data)  
      $.ajax
        url: "/events/" + event_id      
        type: "post"
        success: fetchEvents(event_date)
        data: "_method": "put", "event" :
          "date": event_date              
          "time": event_time              
        dataType: "json"
```

Comment: I'd also recommend changing the string at the top to use CoffeeScript's string interpolation: "/artists/#{user_id}/fetch_events"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just top of the head, could it be,

```
success: -> fetchEvents(event_date)
```

instead of

```
success: fetchEvents(event_date)
```

hope this helps.

Comment: This is it.  The original code is passing the return value of `fetchEvents` as the `success` parameter, but what OP needs is an anonymous function that call `fetchEvents`.

Answer (score -1):

use your ajax part like below

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: data,
success: success,
dataType: dataType
});
```

for details can take help from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Its the same man. My code is just in coffee script. THanks anyway.